# How to make my discord bot respond to *both* custom prefixes and mentions?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a function that retrieves a custom prefix from a database file, but I would like to implement the ability to *also* respond to mentions, as in the `when_mentioned()` function. However, I can not pass in both functions to the `command_prefix` parameter when I am initializing my bot. Is there any way I could go about doing this? I've been searching for answers for the last hour and have found nothing that works yet.

Comment: For who closed my question, I saw that one, that doesn't work for me because I have a *function* that retrieves the prefix, not a static value.